# Random variable functions and dependence

Tags: random-variable, joint-distribution, independence, function

Say we have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$.

Furthermore, say we have two functions $f(X,Y)$ and $g(X,Y)$.

Now, we know $f(X,Y)$ and $g(X,Y)$ will not necessarily be independent. So, in order to derive the distribution of

$$Z=f(X,Y) + g(X,Y)\quad\quad(1)$$

I need to know the joint distribution of $f(X,Y)$ and $g(X,Y)$.

My question is, due to the fact that $f(X,Y)$ and $g(X,Y)$ are made up of the same two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, is it possible to arrive at $(1)$ without the need for a joint distribution?

Comment: $f(X,Y$ and $g(X,Y)$ are _random variables_. So what does it mean hen you say that you want to _calculate_ $f(X,Y)+g(X,Y)$? That is just a random variable. How do you _calculate_ it?

Comment: @DilipSarwate hopefully it's now fixed

Comment: No, it is not. What does it mean to _derive_ $Z$? The _definition_ of $Z$ as the sum of $f(X,Y)$ and $g(X,Y)$ is something that _you_ made up, and it is up to _you_ to explain the reasons why $Z$ equals $f(X,Y)+g(X,Y)$ and not, say, $f(X,Y)+2g(X,Y)$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate derive the distribution of $Z$

Comment: Sometimes you may not need to derive the joint distribution of $f$ and $g$. For example, you may be able to use properties of $X,Y,f$ and $g$ to get around it. Or you may be able to write some transformation from $(X,Y)$ directly to $(f+g, w(X,Y))$ in such a way that $w$ is really easy to integrate out, leaving you with the marginal for $f+g$..

Comment: Define $h(x,y) = f(x,y)+g(x,y)$. Forget about $g$, suppose you're interested in $h$, and let $f$ be *any* hideously complicated function. Your question becomes "is it possible to find the distribution of $h(X,Y)$ without knowing the joint distribution of $f(X,Y)$ and $g(X,Y)=h(X,Y)-f(X,Y)$? From this point of view it should be abundantly clear that $f$ and $g$ are potential distractions: compute the distribution of $h(X,Y)$ however you like. *If it so happens* that $f$ and $h-f$ are so simple that you can easily find their joint distribution and then compute their sum, then so much the better.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the context of the problem. In general, for any $f$ and $g$, yes you would need to find the joint distribution of $f(X,Y)$ and $g(X,Y)$. In some (possibly trivial) cases, this might not be required.

For instance suppose $X, Y \sim N(0,1)$. If $f(X,Y) = X$ and $g(X,Y) = Y - X$, then $Z = Y \sim N(0,1)$. Obviously, the problem can become more complicated if $f$ and $g$ are.